# A bicephal snake

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I am a bicephal snake
>   Lock my tail and I'll hiss at you
>   But if I raise it
>   Be prepared to change course!
>   Some of my sons, sadly, got beheaded
>   For the crime of slithering too much
>   They can still hiss nevertheless
>   But wander easily and often need rest

---

More lines were added to narrow the scope of the riddle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is:

> Earbud headphones

I am a bicephal snake

> Two earbuds each on it's own wire

Lock my tail and I'll hiss at you

> Plug them in for them to make sound

But if I raise it
Be prepared to change course!

> Unplugging them will make sound stop

Some of my sons, sadly, got beheaded
For the crime of slithering too much
They can still hiss nevertheless

> Wireless headphones/earbuds were made because wires get in the way but they make sound just fine

But wander easily and often need rest

> Easy to lose and they need to be recharged

Comment: Welcome to the site and well done! Only the fourth clue is wrong (there is some wordplay at work), the rest is correct ;)

Answer (score 6):

This could be a...

> modern train

*I am a bicephal snake*

> *Bicephal* means two-headed. A modern train may seem to have two heads; one at either end.

*Lock my tail and I'll hiss at you*

> This could refer to applying the brakes at the last carriage opposite to the head carriage. The screeching could sound like a *hiss*.

*But if I raise it

Be prepared to change course!*

> This may refer to inverting the system control where the tail carriage becomes the head and what was the head becomes the tail. Obviously this would change its course along the opposite direction.

Comment: A worthy try, but that's not it, the tail is definitely different than the heads

Comment: More lines were added to narrow the scope of the riddle

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are

> an anchor.

I am a bicephal snake

> most anchors have two flukes (which is how the pointy ends are named, as I just learned from Wikipedia).

Lock my tail and I'll hiss at you

> Ff you set anchor, the chain makes a hissing-like sound.

But if I raise it

Be prepared to change course!

> If the anchor is raised, the ship is not secured in place anymore, so you should know beforehand which course you want to go.

Comment: That's not it, but maybe I should add a line of two to narrow it down. In this case, the "hiss" comes from the heads.

Comment: More lines were added to narrow the scope of the riddle